# JQuery including file with constants

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery constants file which looks something like this:

```
function($) { 
    var Constants =     {
        DECIMAL_SEPARATOR: ",", 
    ....
    } })(jQuery);
```

I'm referencing to the file in the <**head**> section of the HTML page.
Later down I'm using those variables in jQuery script calls, like this:

```
$("$.financeTable input").numeric(Constants.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR);
```

When including the file in the <**head**> element it doesn't work, but when I copy the same code into the <**script**> tag in the same file it works.

How can that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found it, it must be:

```
(function($) {

$.Constants = 
{
    DECIMAL_SEPARATOR: ",", 
    ...
    } })(jQuery);
```

and used like this:

```
alert($.Constants.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are including the file *before* jQuery?

Comment: No ... the script is included after the JQuery script reference.